# Recyclerview search giving java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Tags: android, search, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on recyclerview search in this regard i google many approaches but no one works fine. Now i am implementing an approach which mostly people suggest to implement, but i am getting

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

moreover here is my adapter class:

```
public class CountryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

ArrayList<CountryListModel> getDataAdapter;
private ArrayList<CountryListModel> mFilteredList;
Context context;
ImageLoader imageLoader1;
OnItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public CountryListAdapter(ArrayList<CountryListModel> getDataAdapter, Context context){
    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.mFilteredList = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public CountryListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_country_select, parent, false);

    CountryListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new CountryListAdapter.ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CountryListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    holder.country_name.setText(mFilteredList.get(position).getCountry_name());
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://api.foodomia.pk/app/webroot/uploads/countries/"+mFilteredList.get(position).getCountry_name()+".png").
            fit().centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.unknown_deal).into(holder.country_image);

    holder.main_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onItemClickListner.OnItemClicked(v, position);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getDataAdapter.size() ;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                mFilteredList = getDataAdapter;
            } else {
                ArrayList<CountryListModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (CountryListModel row : getDataAdapter) {

                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                    if (row.getCountry_name().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getCountry_name().contains(charSequence)) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                mFilteredList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            mFilteredList = (ArrayList<CountryListModel>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView country_name;
    public ImageView country_image;
    public RelativeLayout main_view;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);


        country_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag_image);
        country_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name_tv);
        main_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_view);




    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListner {
    void OnItemClicked(View view, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListner(OnItemClickListner onCardClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onCardClickListner;
}
```

}

Comment: Your list contains only 2 elements and you are trying to access 3rd element check that.

Comment: the error is obvious ... with you code: item count == unfiltered count + unfiltered count > filtered count => accessing filtered list with non existing index

Comment: can you please point out error where is that. where me should to make changes

Comment: item count should be equal to the count of the list which you are accessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all .You are using same reference as list as globally. It should be as .

```
public CountryListAdapter(ArrayList<CountryListModel> getDataAdapter, Context context){
        super();
        this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
        this.mFilteredList = new ArrayList();
        this.mFilteredList.addAll(getDataAdapter);
        this.context = context;

    }
```

Second thing count should be return of `filteredList`.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return mFilteredList.size() ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day. actually the error was @Override
public int getItemCount() {
return mFilteredList.size() ;
}